# How to verify a deja-dup backup using duplicity

Tags: fedora, duplicity, dejadup

This evening, I had to hard shut down my computer after some kind of kernel panic.

When I rebooted, I noticed my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` had been replaced with an empty file.

Rebooting to a USB and running `fsck` on my home partition reported that the filesystem was in good shape.

This alone is not a problem. I access to the original key. However, I am concerned that other files may have been similarly truncated.

My last backup, using `deja-dup`, was three days ago, so I could just do a full roll-back, but I would rather just ask `deja-dup` what files have changed since then and look for "suspicious" files.

This seems to be exactly the purpose of `duplicity verify`, so after some man page skimming, I tried:

```sh
duplicity verify --verbosity 4 --no-encryption file:///path/to/backup/ /home/${USER}
```

which ran to completion without reporting changes. At a minimum, I expected my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to be detected, but I have added, removed, and changed other files.

My next try was then the same, but with the `--compare-data` flag:

```sh
duplicity verify --verbosity 4 --no-encryption file:///path/to/backup/ /home/${USER}
```

Which seems to report that every file in my home folder is new, starting like:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Dec 15 11:43:22 2017
Difference found: File . has permissions 1000:1001 700, expected 0:0 555
Difference found: New file .AndroidStudio2.3
Difference found: New file .AndroidStudio2.3/config
Difference found: New file .AndroidStudio2.3/config/inspection
Difference found: New file .AndroidStudio2.3/config/inspection/Default.xml
```

I have had Android Studio installed for months, so it was most certainly in my backup from three days ago, and `ls` reports that `Default.xml` still exists and is 108 bytes long.

As a final effort, I changed the target directory to `/`, since that seemed to be the root when using `duplicity list-current-files`, which required adding some regular expressions to limit duplicity to only consider my home folder:

```sh
duplicity verify --verbosity 4 --compare-data --no-encryption --include-regexp ".*home/${USER}/\.ssh.*" --exclude-regexp ".*" file:///path/to/backup/ /
```

Which had the interesting effect of reporting that my home folder doesn't exist:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Dec 15 11:43:22 2017
Difference found: File home is missing
Difference found: File home/${USER} is missing
Difference found: File home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3 is missing
Difference found: File home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3/config is missing
Difference found: File home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/inspection is missing
Difference found: File home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/inspection/Default.xml is missing
```

At this point, I am certainly just misunderstanding how I should use duplicity. How can I verify a backup generated by `deja-dup`?

`duplicity list-current-files` has output starting:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Dec 15 11:43:22 2017
Tue Feb  6 19:36:56 2018 .
Wed Aug  2 17:32:09 2017 home
Tue Feb  6 00:38:20 2018 home/${USER}
Sat May 13 18:49:24 2017 home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3
Thu Jun 22 19:42:14 2017 home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3/config
Sat May 13 18:57:45 2017 home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/inspection
Sat May 13 18:57:45 2017 home/${USER}/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/inspection/Default.xml
```

Comment: To be clear, the various outputs where I have listed `${USER}` actually had my user account name, I have just replaced them for privacy

Comment: Sompom,

can you try `duplicity verify --compare-data --no-encryption --file-to-restore home file:///path/to/backup/ /` ?

Comment: @ede Thanks for the reply! I have actually been running that command for an hour, and it appears to be working. If you would like to post an answer I will accept it (once it runs to completion and I verify it does what I need), otherwise I will self-answer

Comment: @ede with `--file-to-restore`  and `--compare-data` duplicity seems to have done something useful, in that it correctly noticed lots of files had been modified/added/deleted since the backup was taken, but it still has not detected ~/.ssh/id_rsa is the wrong size. At this point, I am not sure that `--compare-data` does what the man page seems to say it does!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ede and I found the same solution at the same time, in my case [on the duplicity mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2017-03/msg00058.html)

duplicity verify needs the `--compare-data` flag in order to verify the on-disk files, and it needs the `--file-to-restore` flag in order to look in the proper directory, so the final command that solved my problem is:

`duplicity verify --verbosity 4 --compare-data --file-to-restore=/home/${USER} --no-encryption file:///path/to/backup/ /home/${USER}/`

Unfortunately, this still does not detect that `~/.ssh/id_rsa` was damaged. At the same time, trying to restore from the backup restored a 0-byte file... It's quite possible something happened to my file weeks ago.

Comment: hey Sompom,

you correctly found out that duplicity has a quirk where in/exclude only works while looking at the local storage. for restore/verify you will need `--file-to-restore=path` to limit the incrementing over the backup contents. `--compare-data` actually is needed if you want to actually coompare against the local data, w/o it the backup will just be tested for successful restorability. ..ede/duply.net

Comment: When only testing for successful restorability (the backup files still match a checksum stored alongside the backup at backup time), why does duplicity still need the local directory to be referenced (twice)?  I can understand that `--file-to-restore` could be to restrict the test to only the feasibility of a partial restoration - but why must we also reference the actual original location of the data we backed up *if* we are not actually comparing against it?   Or have I misunderstood? (I made the same assumption as @Sompom based on this syntax).

Comment: Also when selecting a specific sub-directory to compare I use a different syntax to above, `--file-to-restore` should only contain the path from within the backup not the full path - eg: `duplicity verify -v4 --compare-data --no-encryption --file-to-restore=bkup-subdir sftp://my-server://archives/duplicity/my-bkup ~/data/bkup-subdir`.  So my local `data` directory is backed up to `my-bkup` on my remote server.  Here we compare a sub-directory under the backup parent dir called `bkup-subdir` with the equivalent on local disk.  Note `file-to-restore` doesn't contain the full path.